# Element is not clickable at point. Other element would receive the click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drupal, behat

How can I bypass this and select the value I need?

## behat #selenium2 #drupal7

When I select "male" from "profile_additional[field_gender][und]"

```
     /**
     * @When /^I check the "([^"]*)" radio button$/
     */
     public function iCheckTheRadioButton($labelText)
         {
         foreach ($this->getMainContext()->getSession()->getPage()->findAll('css', 'label') as $label) {
             if ($labelText === $label->getText() && $label->has('css', 'input[type="radio"]')) {
                 $this->getMainContext()->fillField($label->find('css', 'input[type="radio"]')->getAttribute('name'), $label->find('css', 'input[type="radio"]')->getAttribute('value'));
                 return;
             }
         }
         throw new \Exception('Radio button not found');
     }
```

> Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::selectOption()
>         unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (547, 470). Other
>   element would receive the click: ...
>           (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
>           (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17763 x86_64) (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError)

Comment: You need to wait for the element first, to make sure is present, after that to wait until is visible/clickable and then click it. Also you have click/check actions, the step says radio button and you are using fillField, does't make sense; + use page objects.

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to interact with is hidden beneath some other element. You can try using `Actions` to first move to your element, then try to interact with it. Now I am not an expert in `PHP` and I think this is the language you are using, the action should look something like this:

```
$action = new WebDriverActions($this->driver); 
$action->moveToElement($element)->click()->perform();
```

If you know what element is causing this behaviour, then you can also try waiting for it to be gone, usually done via waiting for `style` attribute to contain `none` as in **display:none**

Comment: How to do this? where do I put that code?

Comment: If your `fillField()` function at some point accepts a `WebElement`, this should go inside.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use scroll to web element using javascript executor

JavascriptExecutor jse = (javascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();"element)

This will resolve your issue

Comment: Where can I put this code? I forgot to mention that i am begginer with behat and selenium, also on automatic testing. Thanks

Comment: Before the element which is not clickable